# showing how two sub-rates make a total rate

Tags: descriptive-statistics, mean

I'm working with a table that shows a total rate and two sub-rates. I have no underlying data just the finished table from an article. The rates are shown as per 1,000 women - the category is marriage per 1,000 for particular groups.

There is Hispanic, Total 16.7 per 1000 (16.7 per 1000 Hispanic women are married), then 13.1 per 1000 Hispanic US born , and 32.6 per 1000 Hispanic foreign born.

How can I show that 16.7 is a combination of 13.1 and 32.6? Is it possible without the original underlying values of each sub-category? It looks like a weighted average type calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like simple algebra assuming the weights need to sum to $1$.

$$13.10w_1 +  32.60w_2 = 16.70.$$
$$w_1+w_2=1.$$
Solve for $w_1 =0.8153846154$
yielding $w_2=0.1846153846$ .

Satisfying the requirements.